# Gaussian fit to a histogram data in python: Trust Region v/s Levenberg Marquardt

Tags: python, python-2.7, curve-fitting, gaussian

My histogram plot clearly shows two peaks. But while curve-fitting it with a double gaussian, it shows just one peak. Followed almost every answer shown in stackoverflow. But failed to get the correct result. It has previously been done by my teacher in Fortran and he got two peaks.
I used `leastsq` of python's `scipy.optimize` in one trial. Should I give my data also?
Here is my code.

```
binss = (max(x) - min(x))/0.05 #0.05 is my bin width
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, binss, color = 'grey') #gives the histogram

x_a = []
for item in range(len(bins)-1):
    b = (bins[item]+bins[item+1])/2
    x_a.append(b)

x_avg = np.array(x_a)
y_real = n

def gauss(x, A, mu, sigma):
    gaus = []
    for item in range(len(x)):
        gaus.append(A*e**(-(x[item]-mu)**2./(2.*sigma**2)))
    return np.array(gaus)
A1, A2, m1, m2, sd1, sd2 = [25, 30, 0.3, 0.6, -0.9, -0.9]

#Initial guesses for leastsq
p = [A1, A2, m1, m2, sd1, sd2]
y_init = gauss(x_avg, A1, m1, sd1) + gauss(x_avg, A2, m2, sd2)    #initially guessed y

def residual(p, x, y):
    A1, A2, m1, m2, sd1, sd2 = p
    y_fit = gauss(x, A1, m1, sd1) + gauss(x, A2, m2, sd2)
    err = y - y_fit
    return err

sf = leastsq(residual, p, args = (x_avg , y_real))

y_fitted1 = gauss(x_avg, sf[0][0], sf[0][2], sf[0][4])
y_fitted2 = gauss(x_avg, sf[0][1], sf[0][3], sf[0][5])

y_fitted = y_fitted1 + y_fitted2

plt.plot(x_avg, y_init, 'b', label='Starting Guess')
plt.plot(x_avg, y_fitted, color = 'red', label = 'Fitted Data')
plt.plot(x_avg, y_fitted1, color= 'black', label = 'Fitted1 Data')
plt.plot(x_avg, y_fitted2, color = 'green', label = 'Fitted2 Data')
```

Even the figure I got is not smooth. It's got only 54 points in `x_avg` Please do help. Can't even post the figure here.

> While plotting on MATLAB, correct results were obtained. Reason:
>   MATLAB uses Trust Region algo instead of Levenberg-Marquardt algo
>   which was not suitable for bound constraints.
>
> The correct results come only when this is shown as a sum of 3
>   individual Gaussians, not 2.

How do I get to decide which algo to use and when?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added another gaussian term. so `p` took 9 parameters in total. Thus

```
p = [A1, A2, A3, m1, m2, m3, sd1, sd2, sd3]
```

Then another term `y_fitted3` was defined and added to `y_fitted`. It then gave a correct figure of two peaks fitting perfectly except for the fact that the curve was not smooth at all! Then searching in stackoverflow led me to use `spline`. i.e.

```
from scipy.interpolate import spline
```

and then at the end,

```
x_new = np.linspace(x_avg.min(),x_avg.max(),30000)
ysmooth = spline(x_avg, y_fitted, x_new)
plt.plot(x_new, ysmooth)
```

Then there it was.
Checking in wikipedia, it says that `L-M` in python also uses `T-R`. So trying again `leastsq` gave the result.
But still, I am not clear about the difference shown in `MATLAB`. Extra inputs will be appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Your problem seems about `mixtures of Gaussian` also known as `Gaussian mixture model`. There are several implementations. [`sklearn`](http://scikit-learn.org/) is worth consideration.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import mixture
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

comp0 = np.random.randn(1000) - 5 # samples of the 1st component
comp1 = np.random.randn(1000) + 5 # samples of the 2nd component

x = np.hstack((comp0, comp1)) # merge them

gmm = mixture.GMM(n_components=2) # gmm for two components
gmm.fit(x) # train it!

linspace = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.hist(x, 100) # draw samples
ax2.plot(linspace, np.exp(gmm.score_samples(linspace)[0]), 'r') # draw GMM
plt.show()
```

The output is
[image]

Comment: Shall i give you the data along x_axis? i still am getting one_peak_gaussian. Thank u for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: sure, share your data!

Comment: do download the entire bundele.
https://www.wakari.io/sharing/bundle/MycrofD/data

Comment: like in the answer given above, there are two histograms. How can I show a gaussian with teo peaks for the right-most histogram. Isn't it clear that it should have two peaks than just one?

Comment: Single Gaussian seems to be better than two Gaussians on your data.

Comment: True that! But, as asked above in the question, MATLAB rejects L-M algo and gives a two peak curve. And that is a sum of 3 GAUSSIANS using Trust Region.

Comment: anyways. i solved my problem. a simple twitch and done it. thank you!

Comment: I am trying to get this code to work, except it is throwing up an error. using the pure code above and also with the data I am feeding it. "ValueError: GMM estimation with 2 components, but got only 1 sample?" Any suggestions?